# precision num2string matlab

Tags: matlab, precision

I got some question relating the precision of the num2str() fctn in MatLab.

```
a=0.11111111111111;
b=a;

Linux/OSX: num2str(a+b,25): ans=0.2222222222222221655465116
Windows: num2str(a+b,25): ans= 0.222222222222222
```

Can anyone explain where the numbers after the 15th decimal place is coming from when using a Linux/OSX system? What is the maximum precision num2str() can obtain?

There is some hint at the num2str documentation that I don't understand completly.

```
Note:   If you specify precision to exceed the precision of the input floating-point data type, the results might not match the input values to the precision you specified. The result depends on your computer hardware and operating system.
```

Comment: It depends on your computer hardware and operating system.

Comment: sorry, this is obvious and no explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `eps` (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html) which gives you the floating-point relative accuracy, which depends on your system architecture.

Have a further look here: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26458-machine-epsilon:

> It roughly means that numbers are stored with about 15-16 digits of
>   precision. If a number is approximately 1, then that means it can be
>   stored with an error of around 10^(-16)
>
> [...]
>
> d = eps(X) is the positive distance from abs(X) to the next larger in
>   magnitude floating point number of the same precision as X"
>
> That says that d = eps(1) is the smallest positive value such that
>   (1+d) is exactly representable and is different than 1.
>
> 1+eps(1) is the smallest representable number greater than 1, a single
>   bit difference in the least significant (smallest change) bit.

Also have a look here to get to know more about it in general (as it is not really a MATLAB specific topic): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: See also: [Floating-Point Numbers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html)

Comment: does windows ignore the error and unix systems show a random error in range of 10^(-16)?

Comment: @moatze again, *it's hardware and operating system dependent*. I get `0.22222222222221999` on my Windows machine.